# Can't get PHP variables in the JS script when setting Highcharts head tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highcharts

Below is an extract of my php file (`recherche.php`) which contains `Html` and `Javascript` (`JQuery Highcharts`) codes and run a `MySQL` query.

But, I can't access the `PHP` variables when setting the JQuery code in the `head` tag.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="./graphics/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./graphics/js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var cat = '<?php echo $categorys; ?>' ; 
        var data1 = '<?php echo $datas; ?>' ;
        var data2 = '<?php echo $datas2; ?>' ;
        var data3 = '<?php echo $datas3; ?>' ;

        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() { 

            chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'containerxx',  
                    type: 'bar'
                    },

                title: {
                    text: 'Average salaries of the sector'
                    },

                xAxis: {
                    categories:  ['Women', 'Men']
                    },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Salary'
                        }
                    },

                series: [{
                            name: 'average salary',
                            data: document.write(data1);
                        },  
                        {   
                            name: 'max salary',
                            data: document.write(data2);
                        },
                        {   
                            name: 'min salary',
                            data: document.write(data3); 
                        }]

            });

        });

    </script>
```

...and below, still in the same file and in the `body` tag, after some more code, are the php variables allocations:

```
    ...
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $category[] = $row[$categorie];

    $data[] = (INT)$row['Salaire_moyen'];

    $data2[] = (INT)$row['Salaire_Max'];

    $data3[] = (INT)$row['Salaire_Min'];
    }
$categorys = json_encode($category); 
echo $categorys ;
echo "<br/><br/>";
$datas = json_encode($data); 
echo $datas ;
echo "<br/><br/>";
$datas2 = json_encode($data2); 
echo $datas2;
echo "<br/><br/>";
$datas3 = json_encode($data3); 
echo $datas3 ;
echo "<br/><br/>";
    ....
```

and this is the command to launch the highchart graphics :

```
    <div id="containerxx" style="width:100%; height:400px; margin:0 auto"></div>
```

But sadly, no chart is diplayed on the screen.

But when I do the same with static values in the same php file it works and I can get the highchart graphic in my webpage.

For example, when I write this script below instead of the one above in the same file, it works and the graphic is diplayed on my page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() { 


            chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'containerxx',  

                    type: 'bar'
                    },

                title: {
                    text: 'Salaire moyen des métiers de l\'informatique'
                    },

                xAxis: {
                    categories:  ['Architecte logiciel', 'Développeur logiciel', 'Infogérance']
                    },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Salaire moyen'
                        }
                    },


                series: [{
                            name: 'Femmes',
                            data: [60000, 45000, 25000]
                        },  
                        {   
                            name: 'Hommes',
                            data: [75000, 48000, 27500]
                        }]

            });


        });

    </script>
```

What do I miss to make my graphic dynamic working with PHP variables despite statics ones?

Comment: Where the screaming caps all that necessary?

Comment: What happens? Do you get errors? What are they?

Comment: What view-source shows? Why `json_encode` on integers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a paid support site, so urging site regulars for a prompt answer is unlikely to help you get answers. Additionally, your question shows very little research effort. You basically dump your complete application here with vague descriptions of how it fails to work and expect us to guess. If you want to write code, you should at least be able to identify what part of your code is not working as expected.

Comment: why do you wrote document.write in 3 places? assign value like data: '<?php echo $datas; ?>';

Comment: @ Arran   You're right, but this is my 3rd day working on it without any solution !!! this is a project for my exam and i'm desperate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your variables BEFORE echoing them in your JavaScript function. So place the PHP that loads these variables above your `<script>`

Comment: can I place the PHP script before the 'head' tag of the html ?

Comment: Yes you can place it wherever you want. You should know that PHP is server side, and since PHP is a programming language it works from top to bottom. eg 1:`echo $string;` 2: `$string = "Hi";` Won't work. 1: `$string = "Hi";` 2: `echo $string;` Will output `Hi`

Comment: what about the "document.write(xxx) in my javascript code : " series: [{ name: 'salaire moyen', data: document.write(data1);" is it correct ?  Or is it any other possibilty to call the js variables : data1, data2, data 3 ?

Comment: I don't think the `document.write` is necessary. I'm not that into JS though so I'm not sure. I'd say try it with and without the `document.write` and see what delivers the best results.

Comment: I've put the php code (with the variable's initialization) before the JS script as you recommand, and I've try to call the JS variables with "document.write" => nothing appears on my screen( it doesn't work) ; and I've try to call the variable without document.write : same result : nothing work....

Comment: What do you mean with 'not working', what is your error. Maybe removing json_encode() from your script fixes it no idea what you want to achieve though.

Comment: I think I should show you the whole code. Can I ? I think it is not possible to write it in this little textarea... how can I ?

Comment: I don't think that would help as I need to know what your error is. I'm just guessing everything here.

Answer (score 0):

```
series: [{
          name: 'average salary',
          data: document.write(data1)
         },  
         {   
          name: 'max salary',
          data: document.write(data2)
         },
         {   
          name: 'min salary',
          data: document.write(data3)
         }]
```

extra semicolon after `document.write(data1/2/3/...)`

Comment: can i simply put :  series: [{
          name: 'average salary',
          data: data1
         },  
         {   
          name: 'max salary',
          data: data2
         },
         {   
          name: 'min salary',
          data: data3
         }]   ?